# Cypress having to wait for typed text to propagate to code

Tags: angular, cypress

```
When('I type {string} in the field', (surname: string) => {
  cy.alias(aliases.surname).type(surname).wait(200);
});

And('I click the Search button', () => {
  cy.server();
  cy.route({ method: 'POST', url: `**search**` }).as('search');
  el('search-button').click();
});

Then('I see that the results match the filter', () => {
  cy.wait('@search').should('have.property', 'status', 200);
  el('data-grid-table').ngSnapshot({ name: 'surname-filter' });
});
```

Why do I need the `wait(200)` on the typing? 200ms seems a lot.

Without this pause, submitting the form via the search button results in the *Surname* value not being picked up by the code and thus not posted with the API request.

**Edit**
Turns out its to do with cycle times in angular forms and observables and the time it takes for form changes to land in the backing model. Still to find an elegant solution.

Comment: Have you tried to using an alias as an argument? Something like so: `cy.wait('@search').then(() => {
  el('search-button').click();
})`

Comment: Perhaps there is some debounce code that happens on the input field that causes the delay?

Answer (score 1):

When Cypress talks about reducing flaky tests, they are referring to the auto-retry mechanism in commands - but some commands by nature cannot be retried. I would say route trapping is one of those.

That does not explain the need for a delay there, but presume behind the scenes there's a lot going on to initialize the server and add a listener to the route.

I am also wondering if Cypress is hoisting that code to the top of the execution queue and restarting (just a supposition).

I would suggest putting that code into a `before()`, which is what a lot of the examples show.